# lxc - Linux container can not access device node

Tags: linux, lxc, lirc

I used the following configuration to bind the lirc0 into the container.

```
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/lirc0 dev/lirc0 none bind,optional,create=file
```

The attribute of the /dev/lirc0 in the host as follows.

```
crw-------    1 root root  251,   0 Jul 16 20:00 /dev/lirc0
```

and I use the lxc-attach to go into the container.  The attribute of
the `/dev/lirc0` in the container is the same as the host

```
crw-------    1 root root  251,   0 Jul 16 20:00 /dev/lirc0
```

But the `/dev/lirc0` can't be open. The error is the "Operation not
permitted" and I'm the supervisor(root) in the container.

How can I get the privilege to access `/dev/lirc0` in the container?

Comment: The issue has been solved. I forgot the permission setting.
If you have the problem with device node access, just adds the "lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 251:* rwm" in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your linux capabilities on the binary you are running.